# Scrollable ODBC cursor in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, cursor

I'm a C++ programmer and I'm not familiar with the .NET database model. I usually use `IDataReader` (`OdbcDataReader`, `OledbDataReader` or `SqlDataReader`) to read data from database. Sometimes when I need a bulk of data I use `DataAdapter`, but what should I do to achieve the functionality of scrollable cursors that exists in native libraries like ODBC?

---

Thanks all of you for your answers, but I am in a situation that I can't accept them, of course this is my fault that didn't explain my problem completely. I explain it as a comment in one of answers that now removed.

I have to write a program that will act as a proxy between client side program and MSSQL, for this library I have following requirements:

- My program should be compatible with MSSQL2000
- I don't know all the tables and queries that will be sent by the user, I should simply add some information to it, make a log, ... and then execute it against MSSQL, so it is really hard to use techniques that based on ordered field(s) of the query or primary key of the table(All my works are in one database but that database is huge and may change over time).
- Only a part of data is needed by the client, most DBMS support `LIMIT OFFSET`, unfortunately `MSSQL` do not support it, and `ROW_NUMBER` does not exist in the `MSSQL2000` and if it supported, then again I need to understand program logic and that need a parse of SQL command(Actually I write a parsing library with `boost::spirit` but that's native code and beside that I'm not yet 100% sure about its functionality).
- I may have multiple clients but most of queries that will be sent by them are one of a few predefined queries(of course users still send custom queries but its about 30% of all queries), So I think I can open some scrollable cursors and respond to clients using that cursors and a custom cache.
- Server machine and its `MSSQL` will be dedicated to my program, so I really want to use all of the power of the server and DBMS to achieve my functionality.

So now:

- What is the problem in using scrollable cursors and why I should avoid them?
- How can I use scrollable cursors in .NET?

Comment: Why do you need a cursor? Can you do a sort of pagination if the data set is to large to be put into memory?

Comment: Exactly. You seriously should realize that you abused the database for many years. Do without scrollable cursors and please also with DataAdapters. Get a book on how to work with databases.

Comment: How many rows does a typical resultset contain?

Comment: @Erno Unfortunately the most common query is `SELECT *` without any condition

Comment: So the users are willing to scroll through millions of lines? I don't buy that. I would try to push the requirements towards more realistic goals so paging, filtering and batch updates will be possible. Scrolling through many lines by many users and being able to update these will cause more locks than any user would want.

Comment: @Erno Startup page of the program contain a grid from all records, sum of some of their fields and also count of it. This is not my design and users won't scroll over it normally, but if I can't open an scrollable cursor I had to pass all the query to the MSSQL, I try it with `DataAdapter` and more than 50000 record is like a cancer to the program, and this is just a test environment, in real world there is usually millions of records.

Comment: It is madness to try and load/parse millions of rows. Use sum/count in the database to calculate the aggregates and provide paging to show the rows. Do not calculate the totals in the client. that is what databases are for.

Comment: @Erno You are exactly right, and that's the reason that I want to have an scrollable cursor for just this madness, design and requirement of that part is not my business, I want to be able to load a couple of records using block cursors and simply move in the result set for rare users that scroll in the main page

Comment: It is not a good reason to have a scrollable cursor. Load a couple of rows using Top functions and force the user to select an ordering of the rows so you can skip already viewed blocks.

Comment: @Erno I can't force the user, that's out of my control. And why cursors are bad while server is dedicated to my program. Somebody should manage the resultset, either me or MSSQL. So why you say it is wrong to let MSSQL do that management?

Comment: Cursors can be horrible in multi-user environments because of locking and memory usage (temp tables etc.)

Comment: @Erno I told you many times, server is dedicated to my application and usually only my program work on it as a service without any user! So what the locking and multi user have to do with my case?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `DataReader.Read()` to skip all rows that I do not want to use when doing paging on a DB which do not support paging.

If you don't want to build the SQL paged query yourself you are free to use my paging class: https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Data/blob/master/src/Griffin.Data/BasicLayer/Paging/SqlServerPager.cs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please have a look at my edited question and say your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you can create queries paged thus. The page number you handle it easily from the application. You do not need to create cursors for this task.

For SQL Server 2005 o higher

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS ROW FROM TABLEA ) AS ALIAS 
WHERE ROW > 40 
AND ROW <= 49
```

For SQL Server 2000

```
SELECT TOP 10 T.* FROM TABLA AS T WHERE T.ID NOT IN
    ( SELECT TOP 39 id from tabla order by id desc )
ORDER BY T.ID DESC
```

PD: edited to include support for SQL Server 2000

Comment: Also this is true for new version of SQL servers, I have clients that already use MSSQL2000 that do not support this feature. So I should try to fight with SQL queries in hope that I can create a paged query where DBMS does not support it or I can use an scrollable cursor to simply work with paging!

Comment: Admittedly, this query only works with SQL Server 2005 or higher. In that case you can use one that is compatible with SQL Server 2000.  SELECT TOP 10 T.* FROM TABLA AS T WHERE T.ID NOT IN
( SELECT TOP 39 id from tabla order by id desc )
ORDER BY T.ID DESC

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it only work if I know the field that data will be sorted on it, but my program generate queries from user input(and also it accept some kind of queries) so it is very hard to generate such queries!

Answer (score 2):

When Microsoft designed the ADO.NET API, they made the decision to expose only firehose cursors (`IDataReader` etc). This may or may not actually pose a problem for you. You say that you want "functionality of scrollable cursors", but that can mean all sorts of things, not just paging, and each particular use case can be tackled in a variety of ways. For example:

**Requirement: The user should be able to arbitrarily page up and down the resultset.**

- Retrieve only one page of data at a time, e.g. using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. This is more efficient than scrolling through a cursor.

**Requirement: I have an extremely large data set and I only want to process one row at a time to avoid running out of memory.**

- Use the firehose cursor provided by ADO.NET. Note that this is only practical if (a) you don't need to hit the database at all during the loop, or (b) you have [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) configured in your connection string.
- Simulate a keyset cursor by retrieving the set of unique identifiers into an array, then loop through the array and read one row of data at a time.

**Requirement: I am doing a complicated calculation that involves moving forwards and backwards through the resultset.**

- You should be able to re-write your algorithm to eliminate this requirement. For example, read one set of rows, process them, read another set of rows, process them, etc.

**UPDATE (more information provided in the question)**

Your business requirements are asking too much. You have to handle arbitrary queries that assume the presence of scrollable cursors, but you can't provide scrollable cursors, and you can't re-write the client code to not use scrollable cursors. That's an impossible position to be in. I recommend you stick with what you currently have (C++ and ODBC) and don't bother trying to re-write it in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but please have a look at my edited question and say your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think cursors will work for you particular case. The main reason is that you have 3 tiers. But let's take two steps back.

Most 3 tier applications have a stateless middle tier (your c++ code). Caching is fine since it really just an optimization and does not create any real state in the middle tier. The middle tier normally has a small number of open sessions to the database. Because opening a db session is expensive for the processor, and after the db session is open a set amount of RAM is reserved at the database server. When a request is received by the middle tier, the request is processed and handed on to the SQL database. An algorithm may be used to pick any of the open sessions, or it can even be done at random. In this model it is not possible to know what session will receive the next request. Cursors belong to the session that received the original query request. So you can't really expect that the receiving session will be the one that has your open cursor.

The 3 tier model I described is used mainly for web applications so they can scale to hundreds or thousands of clients. Were SQL servers would never be able to open that many sessions. Microsoft ADO.NET already has many features to support the kind of architecture I described, so it is not very hard to implement. And the same is used even in non Web applications depending on the circumstance. You could potentially keep track of your sessions so you could open a single session per client, I would first make sure that the use case justifies that. Know that open cursors can take up a lot of resources as well.

Cursors still have a place within a single transaction, it's just hard to keep them open so that the client application can fetch/update values within the result set.

What I would suggest its that you do the following within the query transaction. Store in a separate table  the primary key values of the main table in your query. On the separate table include other values like sessionid and rownumber. Return a few of the first rows by linking to the new table in the original query. And in subsequent calls just query the corresponding rows again by linking to your new table. You will need an equivalent to a caching mechanism to purge old data, and to refresh the result set according to your needs.